# Curl + php steam appi, response error

Tags: php, json, curl, steam-web-api

I'm trying to connect to [this webpage](http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29) of the steam api. The `market_hash_name` parameter is the item I want to search. And as you can see, the response is in the format json. My code is this one:

```
$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=" . urlencode($hash_name);
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 10;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($data, true);

if ($data['success'] == true) {
    echo $url . "<br>";
    echo "Data Found: " . $data;
} else {
    "Data not found";
}
```

Sometimes I get the correct response and everything, but sometimes I get this characters `<Ê+ÍÉÿÿOüË%` as the $data variable. But it still gets inside the if! So it does have the 'success' key in that JSON response, although it's not readable.

EDIT: So I've seen that sometimes the url decides to return `null` instead of the JSON response. I think I get this weird characters when I get the `null` return. But this doesn't explain why It enters to the if sentence :/

Comment: Its looks fine for me

Comment: for me too, even if I check it manually with my web browser it does show me the apropiate results, I can't understand why sometime I get this weird characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need add this to your CURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

See the explanation here : [PHP curl returning strange characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910607/php-curl-returning-strange-characters)